# AWS cli: how to start all machines found by tag

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I can list all machines:
`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Env,Values=my_super_tag" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]' --output text`
And then I wish to start all found machines - is the aws cli expression what allow that?

The workaround can be applying next aws cli command for received output (machines ids) but here I got the problem too:

```
 $ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Env,Values=my_super_tag" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]' --output text\
  | xargs -L1 aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids
' does not existd (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the StartInstances operation: The instance ID 'i-12345677890
xargs: aws: exited with status 255; aborting
```

Strange because with echo
`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Env,Values=spt1" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]' --output text | xargs -L 1 echo aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids`
I get output (executing one of below line works as intended)

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-2123456789
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-3123456789
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-4123456789
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-5123456789
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can embed one command within another, eg:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids `ANOTHER-COMMAND`
```

So, try this:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Env,Values=my_super_tag" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --output text`
```

Comment: Nice try but `An error occurred (InstanceLimitExceeded) when calling the StartInstances operation: Your quota allows for 3 more running instance(s). You requested at least 5`

Comment: @abrasadera you need to request a limit increase with AWS. It's an option on their support tab.

Comment: The default limit is 20 concurrently running Amazon EC2 instances per region. See: [Amazon EC2 limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html)

Comment: There are limits per instance type. Check out your current limits by going to EC2 and then pressing 'limits'. Raise a support ticket to increase when necessary, describing your use case.

Comment: @John Problem solved - I executed your start query on already started instances - anyway output is misleading. After stopping instances and doing your query it works :)

Answer (score 3):

`@John Rotenstein` answer do the job, but due to AWS limits and handling already started instances (my question about this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581977/aws-what-happens-when-i-send-command-to-already-started-instance)), it's good to add to query

```
"Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopping,stopped"
```

So full query then will look like

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Env,Values=my-super-tag" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopping,stopped" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --outpu t text`
```