# AWS: What happens when I send start command to already started instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have AWS instance limit for 10 machines.
I have 5 running.
I can start already started machine:

```
$ aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-123456789
---------------------------
|     StartInstances      |
+-------------------------+
||   StartingInstances   ||
|+-----------------------+|
||      InstanceId       ||
|+-----------------------+|
||  i-123456789          ||
|+-----------------------+|
|||    CurrentState     |||
||+--------+------------+||
|||  Code  |   Name     |||
||+--------+------------+||
|||  16    |  running   |||
||+--------+------------+||
|||    PreviousState    |||
||+--------+------------+||
|||  Code  |   Name     |||
||+--------+------------+||
|||  16    |  running   |||
||+--------+------------+||
```

And when I do start to 5 started machines couple times suddenly I get the message:An error occurred `(InstanceLimitExceeded) when calling the StartInstances operation: Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at least 1`
What is strange because I don't create new instances - all are running already.
After stopping all instances, starting works as before.

What is happening then when I starting already started machines?

Comment: It seems there is instance and instance type limit. E.g. d2.8xlarge is limit to 5 instances , if you need more, you need to increase the limit
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2

Answer (score 1):

Sending a `StartInstances` command for an instance that is already running does not generate an error. It simply returns a response like:

```
{
    "StartingInstances": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-abcd1234", 
            "CurrentState": {
                "Code": 16, 
                "Name": "running"
            }, 
            "PreviousState": {
                "Code": 16, 
                "Name": "running"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So, nothing is happening when you start a Running instance.

You are probably wondering, then, why it gave you the error message. I do not know, but I suspect that the logic that checks quotas to determine whether you can start an instance **does not first check whether the requested instances are running**. It probably looks at the current number of instances running, adds the number of instances you wish to start and then generates an error if total exceeds the permitted quota.